# Why am I getting a Catastrophic failure error when porting VS 2019 extension to VS 2022?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions

I am porting an extension from version visual studio 2019 to 2022.

This extension create a new tool window. Extension worked correctly in very first instace of visual studio after installation Then it is giving below exception in tool window.

It only work again if I delete local data visual studio 17* directory from C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio but only once.

```
Exception details:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF): Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateFrameForToolWindow(ToolWindowCreationResult result, Int32 id, Guid persistenceGuid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.<>c__DisplayClass84_0.<CreateToolWindow>g__CreateToolWindowWorker|1()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, UInt32 flags, Object context, Guid persistenceGuid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, Object context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.<>c__DisplayClass94_1.<<FindToolWindow>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.<>c__DisplayClass94_0.<<FindToolWindow>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ToolWindowCollection.ToolWindowListener.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<<-ctor>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AwaitExtensions.ExecuteContinuationSynchronouslyAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AsyncLazy`1.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<GetValueAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AsyncLazy`1.GetValue(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.FindToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, Boolean create, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Guid& toolWindowType, Int32 id)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.<ConstructContent>g__ConstructContentFromPackage|145_1(WindowFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()
```

Version Used:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - LTSC 17.4 - Version 17.4.4

I did change dll references from old version to new (17.*) Ex: from Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.dll to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0.dll

Please help. I can share more details.

Comment: Does your exception try to remember its previous window location or anything like that?

Comment: No. I don't think my extension have dependency on its window location.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://github.com/simonp22/AnkhSVN/issues/3#issuecomment-499631729

Comment: Same error in same call stack affected https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/incredibuild-frame-construction-error/1125524

Comment: I already disabled setting "Optimize rendering for screens..". Still not working.

Comment: [This doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/migration/update-visual-studio-extension?view=vs-2022#use-shared-projects-for-multi-targeting) mentions that you can update a Visual Studio extension for Visual Studio 2022 by following some steps. This maybe a workaround for you.

Comment: @PranavGour I just had a somewhat similar problem after updating VS2022 from 17.5 or 17.6 to 17.7 and was able to solve it. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77208292/3740047