# Catastrophic failure when loading extension in experimental instance of VS2022 after updating to 17.7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions

After updating Visual Studio 2022 from 17.5 or 17.6 (not sure, which one it was) to 17.7.4 (the current version), I am no longer able to debug the extension I am writing. The extension is written in C#. Whenever I start debugging, the experimental instance of Visual Studio loads and shortly after an error dialog pops up:

> The 'MaintenanceTaskProcessorPackage' package did not load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file 'Path\To\Log\VS22ExpLog.xml'.
> Restarting Visual Studio could help resolve this issue.

Other errors follow and the experimental instance of VS is completely unusable. The log file shows the following multiple times:

```
367 ERROR   Catastrophic failure in extension loading: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) with stack: 
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSettingsStore2.GetSubCollectionNames(String szCollectionPath)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Settings.ShellSettingsStore.GetSubCollectionNames(String collectionPath)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Impl.Settings.ExtensionSettingsCache.<ReadExtensionsAndMarkMissingExtensionsForDeletionAsync>d__91.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Impl.Settings.ExtensionSettingsCache.<LoadInstalledExtensionsFromCacheAsync>d__84.MoveNext()          Extension Manager   2023/09/30 15:26:26.573
368 ERROR   Error retrieving cache version attempt 1 of 5
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))            Extension Manager   2023/09/30 15:26:26.574
369 ERROR   Error retrieving cache version attempt 2 of 5
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))            Extension Manager   2023/09/30 15:26:26.574
370 ERROR   Error retrieving cache version attempt 3 of 5
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))            Extension Manager   2023/09/30 15:26:26.574
371 ERROR   Error retrieving cache version attempt 4 of 5
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))            Extension Manager   2023/09/30 15:26:26.574
372 ERROR   Error retrieving cache version, permanent error, cache will be rebuilt
```

In the debugger, I see lots of exceptions of type `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`.

Removing the experimental folder `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_935fe49dExp` did not help. Executing the commands

```
devenv.exe /rootsuffix Exp /clearcache
devenv.exe /rootsuffix Exp /updateconfiguration
```

(as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51076810/3740047) post) after building the extension does actually help, but only once. As soon as I modify a source file and Visual Studio rebuilds the extension and deploys it again to the experimental instance, the error is back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Update the nuget package `Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools` referenced by the extension project to version 17.7.

**Details:**
Took me a few hours to figure out the cause. Stepping through the decompiled and disassembled VS source code (of the experimental instance) near where the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` occurs, I found out that during the loading of extensions VS tries to query the registry key `\REGISTRY\A\{8128FB0E-7087-45B9-1FB9-C052602201F7}\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\17.0_935FE49DEXP\EXTENSIONMANAGER\INSTALLEDEXTENSIONS` via [`RegQueryInfoKeyW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryinfokeyw). Note that VS is using a [private registry hive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42916299/3740047) (`%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_935fe49dExp\privateregistry.bin`). That key, however, is marked as deleted. So `RegQueryInfoKeyW()` returns [`ERROR_KEY_DELETED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1000-1299-#ERROR_KEY_DELETED) which is then converted into the `HRESULT` `0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)` that appears in the COM exception and the log file.

Why is that key deleted? Setting a breakpoint on `RegDeleteKeyExW()`, I get the following callstack:

```
msenv.dll!Microsoft::VisualStudio::Settings::CVsSettingsStore::DeleteCollection(unsigned short const *) Unknown
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Interop.ni.dll!00007ffd992ba46c()    Unknown
[Managed to Native Transition]  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Settings.ShellWritableSettingsStore.DeleteCollection(string collectionPath) Line 225 C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionEngine.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SettingsStorage.SettingsStoreExtensions.DeleteCollection(Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SettingsStorage.IWritableSettingsStore store, string collectionPath, object syncRoot) Line 113  C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionEngine.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Impl.Settings.ExtensionSettingsCache.ResetCache(Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Impl.Settings.CacheMode updateMode) Line 700 C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionEngine.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Impl.Settings.ExtensionSettingsCache.LoadInstalledExtensionsFromCacheAsync(Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Impl.Settings.CacheMode updateMode, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, int attempt) Line 445   C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionEngine.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Impl.Settings.ExtensionSettingsCache.GetInstalledExtensionsAsync(bool forceRefresh, Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Impl.Settings.CacheMode updateMode, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 160   C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionEngine.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Impl.Settings.InstalledExtensionSettingsList.LoadExtensionsFromCacheAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, bool forceRefresh, Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Impl.Settings.CacheMode updateMode) Line 335  C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionEngine.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.LoadExtensionsFromCacheAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 1092 C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionEngine.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.ScanIfNeededAndInitializeCacheAsync(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> enabledExtensions, bool safeMode, long extensionsChangedTimestamp, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 990 C#
```

So the experimental instance of VS wants to reset some extension cache. Looking at the decompiled `LoadInstalledExtensionsFromCacheAsync()`, the cache gets reset when `!ReadableSettingsStore.CollectionExists("ExtensionManager\\InstalledExtensions", SyncRoot) || !IsCacheVersionValid()` is `true`. And `IsCacheVersionValid()` returns `false` when the `ExtensionManager\InstalledExtensions\CacheVersion` registry key does **not** end with a 2 (whatever that "2" means). If the cache gets reset, the registry key `ExtensionManager\InstalledExtensions` gets deleted. Or at least marked as to be deleted, since apparently some handles to it are still opened, and thus the keys are not removed immediately. That handles are still open is probably the bug and the reason why VS ends up failing to rebuild the cache later on.

When I start debugging the extension and using procmon, I can see that the registry key `ExtensionManager\InstalledExtensions\CacheVersion` initially contains `17.2.2186.59434:1`. It wants to set `17.7.34031.279:2`. Note that after running

```
devenv.exe /rootsuffix Exp /clearcache
devenv.exe /rootsuffix Exp /updateconfiguration
```

without rebuilding the extension, `17.7.34031.279:2` is already the value of `CacheVersion`. So in this case VS doesn't rebuild anything and thus succeeds starting.

Now here is the gotcha: When you build the extension in Visual Studio (in the non-experimental instance!) and it gets deployed to the experimental instance (by the non-experimental instance!), MSBuild actually opens the private registry hive of the experimental instance and sets the `CacheVersion` to `17.2.2186.59434:1`. This causes the experimental instance wanting to rebuild the cache completely at startup, which is buggy and fails as described above.

So, at this point I searched for `"17.2"` in my extension project files and noticed that the project referenced the nuget package `Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools` in version 17.2.2186. After updating it to 17.7.2196, everything works now.